# Substracting a substring

Tags: c

I'm trying to subtract a substring from `params->filename` and append it to query.
I would prefer to avoid extra copying it (params->filename won't change after i exec sprintf , isin't it)?
This is what I tried:

```
(gdb) print params->filename
$4 = 0x8b7d53 "20140317.080051.std"
....
sprintf (query+strlen(query), " %.*s ', to_date('YYYYMMDD.HHMISS')", 0, params->filename+ 15);
```

It doesn't attach  anything. Any clue?

Comment: In the format `"%.*s"`, the first parameter (the one for the `*`) is the maximum number of chars to print from the subsequent string, which is 0 here. It doesn't attach anything - by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `%.*s`, the argument corresponding to `*` means the number of characters to write. You gave argument `0` so it writes `0` characters.

To fix this, either change the `0` to a positive number, or if you want to write the remainder of the string you can just omit the `.*` and the `0,`.